# O que é "nível de granularidade" e como identificá-lo?

Tags: orientação-a-objetos, design-pattern

No livro ***Padrões de Projeto - Soluções reutilizáveis de software orientado a objetos*** de Erich Gamma, logo na introdução do primeiro capítulo temos o seguinte texto:

> "Projetar software orientado a objetos é difícil, mas projetar software reutilizável
>   orientado a objetos é ainda mais complicado. Você deve identificar objetos pertinentes,
>   fatorá-los em classes no nível correto de ***granularidade***, definir as interfaces das
>   classes, as hierarquias de herança e estabelecer as relações-chave entre eles."

Gostaria de saber o que é esse nível de granularidade e como identificá-lo.
Para isso, peço um exemplo.

Comment: Como não fui eu que escrevi o texto , deixo aqui o link com uma boa exemplificação. https://www.componentsource.com/pt-br/help-support/about-us/components

Comment: O link fala que granularidade tem a ver com componentização, mas acho que são coisas distintas.

Answer (score 7):

O nível de granularidade seria basicamente definirmos um critério que iremos adotar para separar as nossas classes, pensando no conceito de orientação a objetos. Por exemplo:
Se temos que cadastrar um funcionário com os dados de Nome, CPF, Data de Nascimento e Salário; pensaríamos a princípio em criar a seguinte classe `Funcionário`:

```
public class Funcionário
 {
     private String nome;
     private String cpf;
     private date datanasc;
     private double salario;

    /*restante do código*/
}
```

Porém se formos pensar em reutilizar esse código, podemos definir uma classe `Pessoa` que vai conter os atributos que são básicos a todas as pessoas:

```
public class Pessoa
 {
     private String nome;
     private String cpf;
     private date datanasc;

    /*restante do código*/
}
```

E assim sendo, nossa Classe `Funcionário` herdaria de pessoa e teria apenas o campo Salário a mais.

```
public class Funcionário extends Pessoa
 {
     private double salario;

    /*restante do código*/
}
```

Portanto, a definição da granularidade é quem nos ajuda a definir qual atributo estará contido em cada classe, tornando assim nosso código melhor reutilizável.

Comment: De meu ponto de vista a resposta esta 98% correta, pois como eu respondi aqui http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/82761/qual-a-melhor-forma-de-passar-valores-para-os-atributos/82803?noredirect=1#answer-82803, a pessoa não depende de um `CPF` ela pode ter um, desta forma seria sim um atributo, mas ela por si não o manipula. Assim eu Criaria uma `class CPF`

Comment: A explicação do @MuriloFechio resume bem uma maneira de entender o grau de critérios adotados para o escopo de uma classe, ou granularidade, entretanto, ela pode ser aplicada há várias vertentes e não somente a esta situação. **Granularidade** pode ser visto como o nível de detalhamento de algo, ou seja, é bem mais que definir atributos.

Answer (score 1):

Granularidade pode ser entendida como o nível de divisão em que os objetos são construídos. Para abordar em termos de classificação *alta* e *baixa*:

[image: nível de granularidade]

Granularidade **baixa** é a divisão em muitos detalhes dos objetos, comumente com muitas composições e poucos atributos por objeto; granularidade **alta** é o nível mais grosseiro, os objetos ficam com muitos atributos e poucas relações.

Faço um paralelo com a representação de notas fiscais em alguns sistemas corporativos, mantida com dois objetos: `NotaFiscalNaoEmitida` e `NotaFiscalEmitida`. Me parece um bom exemplo porque trata de dois extremos dos mesmos dados e é coerente com [esta breve referência](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/flyweight):

> Construir objetos ao nível mais baixo de granularidade fornece flexibilidade ótima, mas pode ser inaceitável em termos de desempenho e uso de memória. *(tradução livre)*

A primeira possui só alguns campos próprios da nota fiscal e faz referência a dezenas de outras entidades como `Cliente`, `Produto`, `Empresa`, `Endereco`, `Imposto`, etc. Tem granularidade **baixa**.

Uma vez emitida e não mais modificada, e para fins de desempenho, consistência do histórico e simplicidade de armazenamento, a `NotaFiscalEmitida` tem uma cópia de todas as informações das relações armazenada em uma única linha do banco de dados. O objeto tem uma configuração absurda com mais de uma centena de campos e nenhuma relação, mas é totalmente independente de qualquer outra entidade e autocontido em seus dados. Tem granularidade **alta**.