# Qual a melhor forma de passar valores para os atributos

Tags: php, orientação-a-objetos

Estou estudando programação orientado a Objeto. Estou muito fascinado como esse novo mundo.

Porém agora me surgiu uma duvida. Acredito que vocês podem me ajudar.

Estou fazendo um classe Pessoa, que tem o atributos nome, idade e sexo.
Porém essa classe terá alguns métodos, são eles:
cadastrar()
exibir()
apagar()
editar()

Gostaria de saber qual a forma correta de passar valores para os atributos e em sequência cadastrar no BD.

PS. Para cadastrar no banco de dados estou fazendo um classe para trabalhar só com o banco. Essa classe do bd, terá o método inserte.

Se é usando "Set" e depois "Get" para acessar o valor de cada atributo?

Usar "construct" para atribuir os valores?

Ou no método cadastrar() ele recebendo os valores dos atributos e em seguida passar esses valores para o atributos:

```
function cadastrar($nome, $idade, $sexo){
      $this->nome = $nome;
      $this->idade = $idade;
      $this->sexo = $sexo;
}
```

Acredito que essa minha duvida é muito simples para desenvolvedores experientes, porém essa é uma questão muito importante para meu estudo.

E se não for pedir muito, como posso saber o momento correto de usar GET e SET e quando um método deve receber "parâmetros"/valores dos atributos ?

Comment: Relacionado: [Para que serve um construtor?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/73530/91) e [Quando usar Setters e Getters?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/43757/91)

Comment: Bem-vindo ao mundo da Orientação a Objetos! É legal esse interesse em aprender um paradigma que é tão utilizado atualmente! Não se acanhe em fazer perguntas: uma pessoa que pergunta é tola por 5 minutos. A que não pergunta pode ser tola pelo resto da vida.

Comment: verdade, hoje posso estar quebrando a cabeça para aprender os conceitos, mas pode ter certeza que amanhã vou estar entendendo e ajudando os próximos que estão com duvida. Muito obrigado @PedroLaini

Comment: Valeu @rray. Já tá ajudando bastante o que vc me recomendou!

Comment: Coitado, mais um que caiu no conto da OOP :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Programação Orientada a Objetos

#### Objeto

> “Objeto é qualquer coisa existente no mundo real, em
>   formato concreto ou abstrato, ou seja, que existe fisicamente
>   ou apenas conceitualmente.”

Objeto incorpora

- estrutura de dados : características (dados) que são os atributos
- comportamento : funções que são os métodos

#### Manipulação

> “O Objeto deve manipular métodos e atributos somente pertencentes a ele”

#### Exemplo

```
class Pessoa{

    private $nome;
    private $idade;

    public function __construct($nome, $idade){
        $this->nome = $nome;
        $this->idade = $idade;
    }

    public function setNome($novoNome){
        $this->nome = $novoNome;
    }

    public function getNome();

    public function getNomeDoMeio();

}
```

#### O que não é orientação a objeto

Objetos que tem relação, que devem ser postos como atributos, mas que estão 
postos como dependetes.

#### Exemplo

```
class Endereco{
    protected $rua;
    protected $bairro;

    public function setRua($rua){
        $this->rua = $rua;
    }
}

class Pessoa extends Endereso{

    private $nome;
    private $idade;

    public function __construct($nome, $idade, $rua, $bairro){
        $this->nome = $nome;
        $this->idade = $idade;
        $this->rua = $rua;
        $this->bairro = $bairro;
    }
}
```

Em seu sistema você pode definir que "toda pessoa tem um endereco",
mas isso nao quer disser que ela deve extender/conter um endereço,
a pessoa é uma pessoa independente de ter endereço ou não.

#### Como relacionar objetos

Alguns objetos

- Repteis
- Mamifero
- Animal
- Baleia
- Lagarto

#### Relacionamento

- Animal -> Mamifero -> Baleia
- Animal -> Repteis -> Lagarto

Ou seja a class animal deve conter metodos e atributos genericos
para comportar ambas as classes, mas nada especifico para determinada class.

#### Manipilando atributos

Os atributos sao pertencentes a classe ou seja dentro da classe voce
pode e deve manipulalos livremente, mas quando um objeto extendo deseja
capturar ou alterar seu valor este deve utilizar os metodos apropriados,
que não são necessariamente o get ou set.

#### Exemplo

```
class Conta{

    private $saldo;

    public function getSaldo();

    public function depositar($valor){
        $this->saldo += $valor;
    }

    public function retirar($valor){
        if ($this->saldo >= $valor){
            $this->saldo = $this->saldo - $valor;
        }else{
            echo "Saldo insuficiente!!!";
        }
    }
}
```

#### Conclusão

Analise bem os atributos de cada class e sempre mantenha eles como `private` ou `protected`,
criando metodos apropriados para sua manipulação.

#### OBS

> “Sair da orientação a Objeto e fazer qualquer coisa 'parecida' é facil.” - Professor

- Material da minha falcudade.

Comment: É mais comum ver `Pessoa extends BancoDeDados {` hehe.

Comment: @rray verdade, nada ver uma coisa com a outra.

Comment: quem disse que uma pessoa não pode ser um banco de dados ? kkkkk

Answer (score 1):

Uma coisa não exclui a outra.

Você passar no `construct` **facilita a criação de um objeto**, sendo que você não precisa criar o objeto e depois setar os parametros nele, pode fazer direto no construct.

Mas, uma hora ou outra você vai precisar de **pegar os atributos de um objeto ou atribuir novos valores a ele**. Para isso, utilizando o conceito de `encapsulamento`, é bom você deixar os atributos como private e utilizar os `setters and getters`.

Comment: Então se eu entendi correto, devo usar sempre GET e SET quando o atributo for privado ?

Comment: E se usar construct recebendo os valores que vou usar apenas para o cadastro (nome, idade, sexo), isso irá "atrapalhar" no momento de que eu for usar o método apagar() ? pois nele não vejo o pq passar nome, idade e sexo.

Comment: sim, pois quando você diz que o atributo é privado, outras classes não conseguem acessá-lo. Os setters e getters são métodos públicos utilizados para acessar variáveis privadas. Esse conceito é chamado de encapsulamento, quando você restringe o acesso à variáveis apenas por métodos públicos

Comment: veja bem: o construct é utilizado para inicializar o objeto. Você pode usar vários constructs diferentes na mesma classe dependendo da sua necessidade. se você consegue chamar objeto.cadastrar( ), objeto.excluir( ) eu não vejo necessidade de passar parametros para eles, já que o próprio objeto que está chamando já possui os atributos.. podendo ser acessados usando $this->nomeDoAtributo

Comment: e se você tiver usando outra classe para esses métodos (o que é mais indicado), chamados de CRUD (create, restore, update, delete), geralmente você passa o objeto inteiro como parâmetro para eles... e dentro do método você acessa os atributos do objeto quando precisar

Comment: nossa, eu pensava que podia existir apenas um construct por classe. Quando há mais de um, como devo fazer? tipo como nome para ele e seus valores?

Comment: No php não tem overload, [É possível criar classes com dois construtores?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/37563/91) @leandroMacedo

Comment: Não sabia que no php não era possível. Então esqueça isso por enquanto. Mas há vários conceitos em Orientação a Objetos que você precisa estudar que facilitarão o entendimento dessas coisas mais a frente, como: Herança, Polimorfismo, Encapsulamento, Sobrecarga de métodos, Sobrescrita de métodos, etc

Answer (score 1):

A melhor forma é aquela que se adequa a situação :).

- Argumentos passados no **construto**r tem a vantagem de já inicializar uma ou mais dependecias do objeto criado, isso garante que atributo não será mais modificado(desde que ele não seja público ou não tenha outro método que modifique seu estado).
- Utilização de **setters**, significa que os valores são opcionais e podem ser chamados a qualquer hora e a operação pode ser realizada a qualquer momento ou seja o valor daquele atributo pode ser modificado durante a vida do objeto.

Answer (score 0):

O construct você usuária para criar um padrão inicia, exemplo zerar os atributos desejados.

Os setters e os getters você usuário na necessidade de alterar e/o capturar um atributo específico, uma dica deixar os atributos da classe private

Mas como vc fez também é possível criar classes para inserir mais de um atributo de uma vez, facilitando a inserção