# PHP MVC Orientação a Objetos

Tags: php, mysql, orientação-a-objetos, pdo, mvc

Estou com 4 tabelas no banco de dados: 
Admin - Professor - Turma - Aluno 
e minha dúvida é :

Eu teria que criar:

AdminModel.class.php 
ProfessorModel.class.php 
TurmaModel.class.php 
AlunoModel.class.php

AdminView.class.php 
ProfessorView.class.php 
TurmaView.class.php 
AlunoView.class.php

AdminController.class.php 
ProfessorController.class.php 
TurmaController.class.php 
AlunoController.class.php

Answer (score 3):

**Sim**, como eu respondi [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/82761/qual-a-melhor-forma-de-passar-valores-para-os-atributos/82803#82803).

No seu caso, todas estas são independentes, não ha nenhum relacionamento entre elas.

Professor é uma característica, assim como aluno, e admin.
Turma é um contexto.

- O Professor pode ser um aluno, assim como um admin, então deve ter estes atributos.
- O aluno por si só so pode ser admin (pode ocorrer, vai depender do seu caso).
- A Turma possui professor, e alunos, então deve ter estes atributos.
- Admin não agrega nada alem de controle, então não tem relacionamento.

#### Concluindo

Nenhuma destas classes são `extends`, a menos que você cria `Pessoa`, ai sim Professor e aluno iram herdar Pessoa.

Comment: Então pelo que entendi, sempre que tiver uma característica unica eu vou ter um (Controller, Model e uma View) para ela. Tipo se eu tivesse "Produtos" e "Serviços" teria que criar um para cada?

Comment: Exatamente, exceto que talvez não haja necessidade de uma view, caso seja uma agregação ou composição.