# Como funciona a estrutura MVC para aplicações Desktop?

Tags: c++, mvc, design-pattern, arquitetura-de-software, engenharia-de-software

Tenho visto muitos projetos Web como frameworks php, asp.net, no entanto li em alguns lugares que o MVC veio antes da web, ele era voltado ao desenvolvimento de aplicações Desktop, no entanto nao encontrei material sobre o assunto.

Nao estou falando de projetos Web, gostaria de saber como funciona em projetos Desktop, principalmente a estrutura de pastas, no entanto em projetos desktop, principalmente C++ eu nao tenho ideia de como isto poderia ser implementado.

Como deve ser implementado o MVC em um projeto C++ e como deve ser a sua *estrutura de pastas*?

Comment: não entendi muito bem, porque aparentemente não tem uma padrão MVC somente para o C++, acho que você consegue adaptar a mesma estrutura de pastas, esse links talvez possam lhe ajudar  https://code.google.com/p/sydmvc/ e https://code.google.com/p/sydmvc/source/browse/#svn/trunk

Comment: Sim @ThiagoFriedman nao tem padrao somente para C++, como eu disse no comeco da pergunta "Tenho visto muitos projetos Web", existe atualmente para Web e para o Cocoa (da apple), eu poderia seguir o padrao do Cocoa, mas eu realmente achei um pouco complexo e nao consegui entender muito bem ele. O problema do link que enviastes pra mim e com a documentacao, existem os arquivos .h, mas nao explica como usar a estrutura de pastas (se e que existe alguma estrutura neste projeto). Obrigado mesmo assim

Comment: Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Comment: @bigown todas me ajudaram, só não escolhi porque não pude colocar em "pratica" e apontar o que acho mais apropriado ao meu caso. Mas acho bem correto o seu argumento *"O MVC não define nada disto. Cada um faz o MVC como bem entender"*

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Não posso agora dar uma resposta muito completa. Mas posso ajudar em alguma coisa.

Essa coisa de organizar em pastas e arquivos é uma coisa que depende da necessidade. O MVC não define nada disto. Cada um faz o [MVC](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/55486/101) como bem entender. O padrão existe para dar uma ferramenta e não para impor um jeito de fazer. Tem várias formas obter o mesmo resultado, aplicando o padrão.

Eu fiquei incomodado com [essa pergunta e a resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/85722/101) também, mas não sei o que fazer com elas então deixei pra lá. É uma receita de bolo que não leva a lugar algum, não faz parte do MVC.

Muitas vezes essa separação nem é necessária. Em outras pode ser necessária uma separação ainda maior, cada componente estar em projetos diferentes. Poucos sabem que o MVC brilha mais quando ele é feito por pessoas diferentes em projetos diferentes. É comum as pessoas seguirem padrões sem se perguntar porque estão usando aquilo. O MVC, como qualquer outro padrão, não solucionam problemas que não existem e eles podem criar um problema novo.

Olha para o jeito que se faz o [Observer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern) em Java e como se faz em C#. Dá para fazer do mesmo jeito em C# e agora dá para fazer de um jeito mais conveniente em Java, mas ambos implementam o mesmo padrão de forma muito distinta.

Dê uma olhada como funciona o [MVC usando Qt](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.5/model-view-programming.html) (provavelmente o que mais pode te ajudar).

Na verdade cada um parece ter uma visão sobre o que é de fato este padrão. Cada *framework* implementa e até mesmo interpreta de um jeito diferente. Alguns acabam mudando um pouco o nome, outros usam o nome de forma inadequada, mas como não sou especialista e nunca vi alguém que garantisse o que é e o que não é MVC, não vou dar meu pitaco (tem que pessoas que se dizem especialistas e já vi que não entendem tanto quanto imaginam).

Leia mais no [artigo do Martin Fowler](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html).

Não sei o quanto está correto e organizado mas [aqui tem um exemplo em C#](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/383153/The-Model-View-Controller-MVC-Pattern-with-Csharp). Não é bem o que você quer mas acho que ajuda.

O que define o padrão em sua essência é que os dados estão em um objeto e eles são burros em relação ao resto, elas só possuem comportamentos relacionados aos dados (regras de negócio) e não à GUI, isto é o *model*. As ações do que a GUI deve executar são recebidas e processadas pelo *controller*. Ele pegará e manipulará os dados do modelo para adequar ao que a *view* precisa. A *view* é que processa a tela recebendo os dados e enviando comandos para o *controller*.

Em geral a tela é montada de uma forma completamente diferente do que se faz com aplicação web. Claro que existem modelos mais novos que podem funcionar de forma análoga à web, enviando um código declarativo que será renderizado por algum cliente, remoto ou embutido.

É possível fazer como na web e ter o modelo e o controlador e criação da visão no servidor e a renderização da visão no cliente (remoto). Isto não é tão simples de fazer, e embora possa existir, nunca vi algo pronto e público para usar desta forma (apenas uma limitação minha, nada impede e acredito que exista, só estou dizendo que o programador comum não saberá como fazer).

Mas o que eu acho que é mais comum é ter tudo isso no cliente. O servidor serve só os dados puros conforme o modelo no cliente solicita.

Em alguns casos é possível ter uma forma híbrida, talvez com o modelo no servidor e o controlador e visão no cliente. Pode nem existir o servidor, eventualmente. Enfim, dá para montar de várias formas.

Um conceito importante que pode ajudar entender a necessidade do MVC e ver como ele realmente é aplicável em qualquer tipo de GUI é a [coesão e acoplamento](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/81314/101). Provavelmente a dúvida venha pela falta de entendimento do motivo do MVC existir.

[Leitura adicional](https://stefanoborini.com/book-modelviewcontroller/).

Tenho visto alguma coisa sobre [RUI](https://reactiveui.net/) e parece melhor que o MVC. Cedo ainda para afirmar.

Posso tentar melhorar a resposta se tiver alguns detalhes extras, mas acho que a maioria das coisas seriam melhor respondidas em perguntas específicas.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Este ponto é um comentário paralelo para mostrar como pode variar. Não que responda o que você quer :)

Answer (score 10):

## O que é MVC

A definição de MVC foi evoluindo ao longo do tempo. Na verdade ela foi bastante simplificada.

De fato este termo nasceu bem antes dos aplicativos WEB e hoje em dia é até difícil dizer exatamente o que ele era naquela época. **Martin Fowler**, que estava lá para ver, escreveu o que se lembra neste artigo: [GUI Architectures](http://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/uiArchs.html).

> A visão mais básica que se tem de **MVC** atualmente é a separação clara dos conceitos de **apresentação**, lógica de **aplicativo** e objetos do **domínio** em três tipos de componentes distintos (*Model*, *View* e *Controller*), cada um com uma responsabilidade específica.

<sub>**Objetos de domínio***: objetos que representam a modelagem do domínio e suas regras de negócio.</sub>

Uma representação gráfica desta separação pode ser a seguinte:

[image: W3Schools - ASP.NET MVC Tutorial]

O que esta imagem nos diz é que *controller* conhece o *model* e conhece a *view*, que também conhece o *model*, que por sua vez não conhece ninguém.

Ou seja, é primordial no MVC que o *model* não conheça ninguém!

## Responsabilidade de cada componente no MVC

As responsabilidades de cada componente podem ser descritas como a seguir:

- **Model:** Modelagem do domínio - entidades e demais objetos de negócio.
- **View:** Apresentação do *model* para interação do usuário - formulários ou páginas web.
- **Controller:** Atende as requisições do usuário, seleciona o *model* (por exemplo uma entidade) e a *view* que o usuário usará para interagir com o *model*.

À parte do MVC, podemos discutir muita coisa, como por exemplo se o *controller* entrega o *model* de fato ou se deve sempre criar um *DTO*, se o *controller* manipula o *model* diretamente ou se usa uma fachada de serviços, se o *controller* deve acessar o banco de dados, se o *model* é quem é responsável pelo acesso ao banco ou se nenhum dos dois acessa o banco... Mas tudo isso vai além do MVC, é bom não confundir.

MVC pode ser associado a outros *design patterns* ou *architectural patterns*.

> O MVC sozinho não tem condições de definir toda a arquitetura e design de um sistema, principalmente de um sistema que atenda um domínio complexo.

## Exemplo de implementação MVC

O MVC busca encontrar solução, por exemplo, para os códigos de regra de negócio que verificam o estado dos controles no formulário ou página web (*view*) para tomar decisões.

Exemplo de código **não** MVC:

```
class Formulario_Titulo {
    void baixar_parcelas_click() {
        sql = "select * from parcelas where titulo = :titulo";

        if checkBox_exclui_parcelas_a_vencer.Checked {
            sql += " and data_vencimento < hoje();"
        }

        parcelas = executa_sql(sql, textBox_titulo_id.Text);

        foreach(parcela in parcelas) {
            ... baixa a parcela
        }
    }
}
```

O código acima está acoplado à *view* (formulário desktop ou página web), e é bem provável que ele acabe sendo replicado quando esta rotina for necessária novamente em outro lugar e isso causa problemas que todos conhecemos muito bem.

Em um sistema que **é MVC**, o código acima se transformaria algo assim:

```
class Formulario_Titulo {
    botao_baixar_parcelas_onClick += patch();
}

class Titulo_Controller {
  void patch() {
    titulo.baixar_parcelas(textBox_titulo_id.Text, checkBox_exclui_titulos_a_vencer.Checked);
  }
}

class Titulo {
    void baixar_parcelas(String titulo_id, boolean exclui_titulos_a_vencer) {
        sql = "select * from parcelas where titulo = :titulo";

        if exclui_titulos_a_vencer {
            sql += " and data_vencimento < hoje();"
        }

        parcelas = executa_sql(sql, titulo_id);

        foreach(parcela in parcelas) {
            ... baixa a parcela
        }
    }
}
```

Então eu parti de um código que acumulava toda a implementação no formulário e dividi as responsabilidades em três componentes: Formulario_Titulos (*view*), Titulos_Controller (*controller*, naturalmente) e Título (*model*).

Existem mil maneiras de se implementar MVC, dependendo da linguagem, plataforma, frameworks e outras decisões arquiteturais e de design. O exemplo acima é apenas um pseudo-código para apresentar uma visão mais concreta do conceito.

## Organização de um projeto MVC

Até aqui eu procurei dar uma noção do que é MVC pois não adianta tentar descobrir como organizar um projeto MVC sem ter esta noção.

A organização dos arquivos e pastas também vai depender da escolha da linguagem e frameworks que se vai utilizar - alguns frameworks tem uma organização padrão sugerida que vai facilitar o trabalho com ele, e você pode ainda fazer o seu próprio framework ou usar framework nenhum, estabelecendo seu próprio padrão.

Para ter uma ideia, veja a organização padrão do **Ruby On Rails** (um framework para aplicações Web baseado em RESTFull e MVC):

<sub>Nos exemplos, considere que o sistema provê um CRUD para uma entidade chamada *Cliente*.</sub>

```
    nome_app/
            app/
                views/
                    clientes/
                        index.html.erb
                        new.html.erb
                        show.html.erb
                controllers/
                    clientes_controller.rb
                models/
                    cliente.rb
```

Veja também a organização padrão do **ASP.NET MVC** em C# (bem parecida com a do Rails):

```
    Nome_App/
        Views/
            Cliente/
                Index.cshtml
                AlgumaViewEspecial.cshtml
                _AlgumaParcial.cshtml
        Controllers/
            ClienteController.cs
        Models/
            ClienteModels.cs
```

Veja ainda como um dos meus projetos (**Java JSF**), usando *facelets*, é organizado:

```
    nome_app/
        /src/main/webapp/               (Views)
                    cliente/
                        index.xhtml
                        new.xhtml
                        show.xhtml
                        _algumTemplate.xhtml
        /src/main/java/                 
                    app/                (Controllers)
                        cliente/
                            Cliente_Controller.java
                    domain/ 
                        cliente/        (Model)
                            Cliente.java
                            ClienteRepo.java
                            Categoria.java
```

Observe que na minha estrutura em Java eu mencionei entre parênteses onde está cada componente do MVC, pois isto pode não estar óbvio na nomenclatura que eu utilizo, uma vez que a minha nomenclatura procura dar ênfase a outros aspectos da arquitetura e não ao MVC em si (mesmo este projeto usando MVC). Eventualmente esta estrutura será ainda mais complexa se a complexidade do domínio demandar.

E existem muitas outras pastas em cada projeto, que atendem outros aspectos e responsabilidades do sistema.

## Conclusão

Uma vez entendendo o conceito básico de **MVC**, seu objetivo (estabelecer uma separação clara entre as responsabilidades de apresentação e negócio), a responsabilidade de cada componente e o relacionamento entre eles, você fica livre para escolher a estrutura do seu projeto ou para se adaptar à estrutura sugerida pelos frameworks escolhidos se for o caso.

E o fato de o aplicativo ser Web ou Desktop não é o fator primordial de decisão - você pode basear a estrutura de um projeto Desktop em qualquer um destes exemplos Web, a diferença é que a *view* aqui é declarada usando tags de bibliotecas Web, e no aplicativo Desktop será declarada usando ferramentas desktop.

Answer (score 7):

MVC é uma padronagem do desenvolvimento orientado a objetos. A aplicação tem no mínimo uma classe View, que toma conta exclusivamente de desenhar e manter a tela. A classe Model toma conta das "regras de negócio" do aplicativo, inclusive conversar com o banco de dados se houver. (Alguns textos falam do Model como se ele fosse apenas uma representação passiva do banco de dados, mas eu entendo que isto é errado. O nome disso é ORM - Object-Relational Mapping; o Model pode fazer uso de ORM mas ORM sozinha não pode ser chamada de Model.)

O Controller é idealmente uma classe bem simples, uma camada fina entre Model e View. Numa aplicação multi-plataforma, o Model tenderia a ser facilmente portável, enquanto View e Controller teriam grandes dependências em cada plataforma e portanto seriam específicos para cada platafora.

Então, se você fizer essa separação em três classes no seu projeto C++, está seguindo a padronagem MVC.

Bem, isso é o ideal. No mundo real, a gente acaba desviando disso. Um pouco porque as plataformas encorajam isso. Quando você inicia um aplicativo Android, sempre existe uma Activity, que faz as vezes de controller, mas não há um template de Model, então a tendência difícil de evitar é implementar a "inteligência" do aplicativo dentro da Activity, e depois fica difícil separá-la para reaproveitar em outro lugar. O mesmo acontece no iOS, a classe descendente de UIViewController já está lá e acaba recebendo todo o código não-visual também, embora a idéia original fosse que o Controller apenas auxiliasse as Views no que elas não podem fazer sozinhas, e compatibilizar com o Model. (Ao menos as classes View estão claramente delimitadas nestas plataformas, então a promiscuidade ocorre mais entre Model e Controller.)

Comment: possa ser sincero, a resposta nao esta ruim, mas realmente ficou ainda vago de "como fazer", se entendi o que disse, voce que dizer que preciso de 3 classes "extensíveis", entao a partir delas irei criar por exemplo o controllerfoo.h e controllerfoo.cpp que são estendidos do controller.h (apenas um exemplo), viewfoo.h e viewfoo.cpp que são estendidos do view.h e modelfoo.h e modelfoo.cpp que são estendidos do model.h (provavelmente o que gera o widget). O que nao ficou muito claro e como fazer a interação do foocontroller.cpp com os demais. Mas ainda sim me parece um resposta promissora.

Comment: É, existe aí uma liberdade de layout de classes. Não é obrigatório estabelecer uma hierarquia começando com as classes abstratas. Dito isto, Views normalmente têm uma superclasse porque existe um relacionamento de contém-está contido entre, por exemplo, a view da tela e as views dos controles.

Comment: Seguindo seu comentário, "foocontroller" é quem conhece tanto o Model quanto o View. O Controller pode inclusive possuir os objetos Model e View, de modo que a destruição do controller é quem remove os outros dois objetos.

Comment: Dá para fazer MVC até sem classes :)

Comment: No caso em aplicacoes com C++ que possuem Widgets eles possuem sim Classes, um exemplo o QT que as classes são estendidas do QWidget e são associadas ao arquivo de template (que e um xml)

Comment: Mas dá para fazer MVC sem. Não estou dizendo que deve ou que uma implementação específica dá.

Comment: Nao sei se o ultimo comentario foi pra mim @bigown, na verdade o meu comentario seria apenas uma adição ao seu comentário, pode-se fazer sem classes, como no QT usamos classes pros widgets geralment :)

Comment: Eu só deixaria de fora a parte de que o Model conversa com o banco pois, como você mesmo colocou, o Model é idealmente desacoplado dos demais componentes. De qualquer modo acho que é uma resposta bastante elucidativa e correta. +1

Comment: @bigown de fato dá pra fazer em C, em Assembler... não se usa MVC ou mesmo orientação a objetos "pra bonito". A intenção do MVC é você ter um Model portável e claramente separado do View.