# Como acessar variáveis de outra classe de objetos por array?

Tags: java, array, classes

Tenho 2 Classes,sendo elas : **Percurso** e **Custos**.

**Percurso** :

```
public double getKmPercorrida() {
    return kmPercorrida;
}
public void setKmPercorrida(double kmPercorrida) {
    this.kmPercorrida = kmPercorrida;
}
public double getValorCombustivel() {
    return valorCombustivel;
}
public void setValorCombustivel(double valorCombustivel) {
    this.valorCombustivel = valorCombustivel;
}
public double getValorPedagio() {
    return valorPedagio;
}
public void setValorPedagio(double valorPedagio) {
    this.valorPedagio = valorPedagio;
}

public void cadastrarPercurso() {
    setKmPercorrida(Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Digite os km percorridos : ","Km percorridos",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE)));
    setValorCombustivel(Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Digite o valor do combustivel : ","Combustivel",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE)));
    setValorPedagio(Double.parseDouble(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null,"Digite o valor do pedágio : ","Pedágio",JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE)));
}

public void listarPercurso() {
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Km percorridos : " + getKmPercorrida() +
            "Valor do combustivel : "  + getValorCombustivel() +  
            "Valor do pedágio : " + getValorPedagio());
}
```

**Custos** :

```
private double totalPercurso;


public double getTotalPercurso() {
    return totalPercurso;
}

public void setTotalPercurso(double totalPercurso) {
    this.totalPercurso = totalPercurso;
}



public String calcularViagem(Percurso [] p) {


    return "";



}
```

Na classe **Custos** no método **calcularViagem** eu tenho que receber um array de objetos do tipo Percurso,e calcular o valor da viagem,sendo então :

```
totalPercurso = (kmPercorrida * valorCombustivel) + valorPedagio
```

A variável **totalPercurso** vai receber as variáveis do objeto Percurso e calcular todas elas através do método em que ele está.

Mas como posso fazer isto ?

Comment: Não ficou claro. Quando se trata de programação orientada a objetos, não se fala em "variáveis da classe" e sim "variáveis do objeto". Mas não estou vendo nenhum objeto do tipo Percurso sendo usado na sua classe "Custos".

Comment: Estou recebendo ele como um array de objetos ali no método calcularViagem,e com isto,tenho que calcular o total do percurso da classe Percurso.

Comment: Novamente, não faz sentido falar em "total da classe". A classe é só um molde pra criar objetos. Além disso, o que quer dizer com "total"? Total de quê?

Comment: Total do valor junto com as outras variáveis.Eu tenho que somar todas elas pela variável totalPercurso,e isto através pelo parâmetro que estou passando que é o objeto Percurso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Considerando que este total que você deseja calcular é o total de todos os atributos, o cálculo (já que não está claro na pergunta) ficaria assim:

```
public String calcularViagem(Percurso[] p) {
  totalPercurso = 0;

  for (int indice = 0; indice < p.length; indice++) {
    Percurso percurso = p[indice];

    totalPercurso = totalPercurso + (percurso.getKmPercorrida() * percurso.getValorCombustivel()) + percurso.getValorPedagio();
  }

  return String.valueOf(totalPercurso);
}
```

E o método para testar a solução:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Percurso percurso1 = new Percurso();
  percurso1.cadastrarPercurso();
  percurso1.listarPercurso();

  Percurso percurso2 = new Percurso();
  percurso2.cadastrarPercurso();
  percurso2.listarPercurso();

  Percurso[] percursos = new Percurso[]{percurso1, percurso2};
  Custos custos = new Custos();

  System.out.println(custos.calcularViagem(percursos));
}
```

---

Agora algumas observações:

- O retorno do seu método está como `String` quando na realidade é um cálculo. Ele deveria ser igual ao tipo das suas variáveis quantitativas, que no caso é `double`;
- Você está misturando elementos de apresentação com elementos de negócio, no caso utilizando `JOptionPane` dentro da suas classes de negócio/modelo. Veja mais como poderia organizar melhor o seu projeto na resposta da pergunta [Como funciona a estrutura MVC para aplicações Desktop?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/85848/como-funciona-a-estrutura-mvc-para-aplica%C3%A7%C3%B5es-desktop/86132#86132) que apesar de ser em `C++` pode ser aplicada a praticamente qualquer tipo de projeto.

Comment: O total seria a soma de todas as variáveis do objeto Percurso,e isto eu teria que fazer pelo parâmetro que estou recebendo.O seu exemplo me ajudou,mas eu preciso é calcular todas as variáveis do objeto e não só uma.E o modelo MVC eu já entendo sim,mas como é uma aplicação que estou fazendo simplesmente em casa e não no trabalho,eu não uso ele então.

Comment: @Mondial Edite sua pergunta descrevendo melhor o que é esse cálculo. Com exemplos, por favor, porque não estamos entendendo.

Comment: @PabloAlmeida Tudo bem,me desculpe se não deixei muito claro a pergunta,sou novo aqui e ainda não sei muito bem como postar corretamente.

Comment: @Mondial alterado para corresponder com seu enunciado

Comment: @Sorack Obrigado,testei sua resposta e deu certo.

Comment: @Mondial acho que a melhor abordagem é usar um `List` e não um `array`.

Comment: Consegui fazer funcionar certinho com a sua abordagem,muito obrigado.Mas por que seria então melhor usar List e não array ?