# Cardinalidade do MVC no desktop

Tags: java, mvc, aplicação-desktop

Qual deve ser a cardinalidade do MVC desktop?

**Models:** tipicamente um, pode haver mais.

**Views:** quantas estiverem observando o modelo, ou uma árvore, representando aproximadamente a GUI? Visão deve seguir o padrão Composite?

**Controllers:** um, ou um para cada Model, ou um para cada View?

Ou outros valores?

Comment: Se fizer 1:1 está usando a técnica errada. Não acho que seja possível responder além disso.

Comment: @Maniero Ok. Estudar mais... ler o GoF... ô padrãozinho complicado.

Comment: Vou responder..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A ideia do MVC é justamente não ser um para um. Muitos problemas, muitos mesmo são assim, então fica claro que o MVC não deva ser usado.

Não é que não possa, mas dá para fazer algo mais simples se for essa cardinalidade. Um erro comum na maioria dos projetos de web é as pessoas fazerem MVC porque disseram que é o certo, mas não disseram como usar, então a pessoa adota como receita de bolo para tudo. Em desktop talvez errem menos porque é raro usar esse padrão.

A idea dele é que *views* devem poder chamar quais *actions* de quais *controllers* quiser, e um *controller* pode acionar as *views* que forem necessárias.

Uma ação pode ser acionada por algo que não seja uma visão definida no sistema. Tem *action* que não aciona uma *view* (não sei se em desktop ocorre).

Em alguns casos é possível que de fato uma *view* possa estar relacionada com um *controller*, mas é pura organização e não deve ser obrigatório. Digo isso até porque em tese você poderia ter um *controller* para cada *action* e nada muda de fato para o sistema, ou ter um único *controller* com todas as *actions* do sistema inteiro. Organização do projeto nada tem a ver com o padrão. Cada projeto pede uma coisa diferente. A ação é algo mais importante que o controlador.

E é comum haver certa [ortogonalidade](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/195461/101) entre eles.

Um controlador deve poder acessar os modelos que quiser, porque os processos são complexos e tem muita coisa relacionada. Não deve haver uma relação de 1:1 a não ser por coincidência. E não é incomum que ele gerar *model views* para a visão consumir.

Eu discordo que deva existir apenas um modelo. Tem uma pergunta que fala sobre isso, mas não achei (alguém?). Até existe algo que pode ser chamado de **O** modelo no sentido de ter toda modelagem do sistema, mas cada objeto é um modelo, então pra mim você tem vários modelos sempre. Note que se existisse um só modelo a pergunta estaria errada na parte que relaciona com *controller*.

Eu não sei se entendi bem a parte que fala da *view*. Mas posso garantir que a necessidade de telas deve decidir quais são as exigências, não outras coisas. Parece que o Composite não tem relação direta, mas posso ter perdido algo.

Assim como os modelos devem ser criados de acordo com a necessidades dos objetos (de negócios). São necessidades diferentes.

Os controladores deveriam idealmente existir de acordo com a necessidade de agrupamento de ações relacionadas, e estas devem existir enquanto houver processos claros que devem ser acionados.

Talvez queria falar sobre organização do projeto. Isso não ajuda muito, e é como OOP, não tem regra que você decora e tudo fica lindo, tem que saber montar de um jeito que faça sentido, e é difícil acertar em algo que seja complexo.

Vou dar um exemplo. Controle de comissão de vendedor faz parte de vendas ou do financeiro? A resposta é mais complicada do que parece e só quem entende do assunto consegue responder bem. Nenhum dos dois? É separado? Mas ela só é acionada quando há uma venda e quando há o recebimento.

## MVC no desktop

Eu nunca vi um sistema bom de MVC pra desktop (pode existir). Desktop é *frontend*. Recentemente vi alguns dos **melhores** especialistas de *frontend* dizerem que MVC no *browser* não faz sentido, só vale para o *backend*. Eu não me aprofundei no assunto, mas me pareceu fazer sentido e ouvi de gente que não é fanfarrão. Se isso é verdade, por que seria bom para o desktop?

MVP, HMVC, MVVM, e outras coisas do tipo não é o mesmo que MVC.

Ainda não tenho uma resposta definitiva e essa é a melhor resposta que posso dar, ainda que alguns não gostem porque querem sempre a verdade definitiva.

**Talvez** fizesse sentido para o desktop ser 1:1, e aí ficaria certo que ele não deve ser usado nesse tipo de tecnologia.

O 1:1 é bom pra CRUD. CRUD não precisa de MVC. #Falei.

Eu admito que possa haver outra visão para isso.

Eu entendo que algumas pessoas se acostumaram tanto fazer assim que fica mais fácil para elas sempre usarem o MVC, até onde não precisa, mas isso é gosto e não engenharia (e nenhum problema em por gosto na frente quando ele faz sentido).

Quando começa automatizar certas coisas ou ter contato do V com o M, ainda é MVC? Tem quem diga que pode, outros que não pode, então entendo nada.

Eu já vi tanta coisa por aí que fica complicado dizer o que é certo. E sempre falo que se tem muita opinião diferente sobre algo, boa coisa não é. E muita gente lerá isso e falará que sabe o que é o certo, mas o certo de cada um é diferente, por que o dele é o certo mesmo, só por que foi o que ele aprendeu?

E tem um certo originalmente, mas é o que as pessoas usam? Se usam diferente, por que chama de MVC? O mesmo problema das pessoas chamarem OOP o que não é?

Algumas fontes são tão ruins que chamam ele de *design pattern*.

Relacionado (talvez eu atualize): [Como funciona a estrutura MVC para aplicações Desktop?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/85848/101).

Comment: _"Uma ação pode ser acionada por algo que não seja uma visão definida no sistema."_ No caso do desktop eu penso em um player de música que é acionado quando acaba uma música e começa outra.  Outra coisa que penso sobre MVC é quando entram threads na história,  como faz daí? Trata normalmente e agenda um Runnable? Ou tem algum tratamento especial?

Comment: Aí já começa ter formas específicas em cada tecnologia.

Comment: _"Composite."_ Vi no GoF mas não me aprofundei. _"Os modelos devem ser criados de acordo com a necessidades dos objetos (de negócios)."_ Os modelos não são os próprios objetos de negócios?

Comment: Em geral sim, que nada tem a ver com as outras partes do MVC, pelo menos não diretamente (pode ter alguma relação, mas não precisa ser).

Comment: _"Aí já começa ter formas específicas em cada tecnologia."_ Acho que não fui claro. O que eu queria saber é se dá para entrar threads na história sem quebrar a ideia do MVC de separar as coisas.

Comment: Eu acho que sim, não me parece que uma coisa tenha relação com outra, MVC não precisa estar nem no mesmo processo ou máquina.